# How to use a global-portlet in liferay?

Tags: liferay-6.2

I am new to liferay ,I got one doubt ,if we want to use a global level service layer we need to place  the specific portlet xxxxservice.jar file into lib/ext from webapps/portletname/lib folder. 
But is there any solution automatically place the jar file into lib/ext folder while deploying it self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatism, but if you need the services of one plugin (A) within another plugin (B), you can declare in B's `WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties` the following property:

```
required-deployment-contexts=A
```

This will only deploy B when A has already been deployed. Further, it will copy `A/WEB-INF/lib/A-service.jar` into `B/WEB-INF/lib/` upon deployment of A. Thus the library will be available, but it will not be on the global classpath. Note that changes to the global classpath (assuming you use tomcat) would require a restart of the appserver.